# Is it possible to specify that that task.delay or task.apply_async should fail if celeryd isn't running?

Tags: celery, django-celery

I'm using djcelery and djkombu. I would've used RabbitMQ (as that's the recommended option), but RabbitMQ uses too much memory on my VPS and I'm being a cheapskate.

I'm thinking that it would be nice in my app for an exception to be thrown if my code tries to schedule a task and celeryd isn't running. This is sort of a backup plan for having celeryd monitored by supervisor, nagios, etc.

At first I thought the `immediate` setting would do this, but it didn't work with my Django ORM configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is mainly that with this commands you are sending simple message to the broker, and basically the broker just store the message and wait for someone that consume it.
The cool thing of this architecture is that if a celery worker goes down for two our when it run again starts to fetch all the olds scheduled tasks that are in the broker.
If you don't want this behavior for your project maybe celery is the wrong choice.